# Show these two are equivalent: 1) $\exists \ k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k=\mathbb{0}$ 2) $p_A(\lambda)=(-1)^n\lambda^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A \in M_{n \times n}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$. I would like to show these two are equivalent:

1) $\exists \ k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k=\mathbb{0}$

2) $p_A(\lambda)=(-1)^n\lambda^n$

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This approach is more pedestrian than lhf's answer, but the method may be useful for other problems:

Since $A$ is a root of the polynomial $\lambda^k$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $\lambda^k$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial only has one irreducible factor: the linear factor $\lambda$.

Since the set of irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial always agrees with the set of irreducible factors of the minimal polynomial, this implies that $\lambda$ is the only irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Hence the characteristic polynomial must be $(-1)^n \lambda^n.$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint;* If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$.