# Trace of a nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and $T:\,V \longmapsto V$ a linear map.

The **trace** of $T$, $tr(T)$, is the trace of any matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ related to $T$ with respect any basis of $V$.

I have to show that

**Lemma** If $T$ is a nilpotent linear map, then $tr(T)=0$.

*proof.* We know that if $T:\,V \longmapsto V$ a linear nilpotent map of a a finite-dimensional vector space, then then there exists a basis of $V$ such that the matrix representation of $T$ is upper triangular with zero diagonal elements. Then $tr(T)=0$.

**QUESTION:** My teacher uses a different proof of this lemma, but I think there is something missing...

*proof.2*
First of all it is easy to show that the trace of a linear transformation is also equal to the sum of the roots of his characteristic polynomial $p_T$ in a splitting field $K$ of $p_t$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Also if $T:\,V \longmapsto V$ a linear nilpotent map then its only eigenvalue is 0.

Then $tr(T)=0$.

---

I think this proof is true only if the field $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed: if so, $\mathbb{F}$ contains all the roots of $p_T$. Then every root of $p_T$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and so it must be zero.

But if $\mathbb{F}$ is **not** algebraically closed, it is possible that there are some roots of $p_T$ that are not in $\mathbb{F}$. So we are not sure that every root of $p_T$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, and then I cannot use the fact that every eigenvalue of $T$ is 0 to show that $tr(T)=0$. Am I wrong??

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196434/show-these-two-are-equivalent-1-exists-k-in-mathbbn-such-that-ak-m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument you describe is perfectly correct. Your matrix can be viewed as having elements in $\mathbf{F}$ *or* as in $\overline{\mathbf{F}},$ since $\mathbf{F} \subseteq \overline{\mathbf{F}}.$ The argument shows that if you think of the elements as lying in the closure, the trace is zero. But however you think of them, $0\to 0$ under the inclusion $\mathbf{F} \to \overline{\mathbf{F}}.$

Comment: Thank you so much!! In terms of vectorial spaces if $\overline{F}$ is a splitting field of $p_T$ over $F$ then I can consider $\overline{V}=\overline{F}-$ vectorial space (i.e. $\overline{F}^n$) such that $\dim_{F}V=\dim_{\overline{F}}\overline{V}$. Fixed a basis for $\overline{V}$, if $A \in M_n({F})$ is a matrix of T, then $A$ is also a matrix of a linear map $\overline{T}:\overline{V}\longmapsto{\overline{V}}$ which is nilpotent (as A is a nilpotent matrix). But now every root $\lambda$ of $p_{\overline{T}}=p_{T}$ is an eigenvalue for $\overline{T}$ and then it must be $\lambda=0$.